# Adding array of textbox using javascript into html

Tags: php, javascript, html, vbscript

Is something wrong with my code?

```
    <script>
        function add(){
            /* Get your form */
        form = document.getElementById("test");
            /* Create your input element */
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type="text";
        input.name="array['artists']";
            /* Append to form */
        form.appendChild(input);
        alert("done");
        }
    </script>

<table>
<tr>
 <td align="right">Artist/s:</td>
 <td><form id="test" enctype="multipart/data-form" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="artists"/>
 <input type="button" onclick='javascript: add()'/></form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Im trying to add another textbox below another but nothing happened. What should i do?

Comment: Where is the PHP or VBScript in this question?

Comment: `<input type="button" onclick='add();'/>`

Comment: I tried that one. I dont if i missed a semi-colon, double quotation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkDKr/1/)

I just put a call to `add()` inside a `setTimeout` so it would execute a second after the page loads.

Are you just missing the call to `add()`?

**edit**: I didnt originally see the onclick bound. new working [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/BkDKr/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me too.

When I first put it into an html file, Internet Explorer wouldn't let me run the javascript because the html file was local to my computer. Try another browser if that's what you're using. Or just click yest to allow it in IE if that's the case.

Comment: Im using gc as my browser. I tried it on mozilla too but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as well. Try testing in another browser..

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML-formatting is not right. This is why the input-box (TextBox) is added after the 'add'-button and not underneath it as you would like.

You can try the following code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableAddRows");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.appendChild(input);
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(row);
```

Add an id to the table (in the sample "tableAddRows").

Also, I added the Submit-button in a different table, like so (there are neater solutions):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also place the form-element around both tables.

I would also suggest to use [JSRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/) or [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) to achieve your purpose.

Here's the [sample](http://sdrv.ms/Rddbsn) code, if your still trying to figure it out.